# Unable to request server because invalid or expired ssl - how to ignore?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

I Am trying to make a request to server, but however my server is setup with custom ssl `openssl req -new -x509 -keyout server.pem -out server.pem -days 365 -nodes` however how can I set to false verification ssl similar to python `requests.get(url,verify=false)`

**client**

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(html);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add some logic instead skipping all validation. You may want to check the validation error and ignore it only if it is cert expired but raise other errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following to your code:

```
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

So the endresult would be:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(html);
                    }
                }
            }
```